# How we can keep the first displayed line unchanged in webbrowser while form is being resized?

Tags: delphi, resize, twebbrowser

There is a Webbrowser1 on the Delphi RIO application form with Align=alClient. Webbrowser's content is scrolled so the first displayed line is not the first line of webbrowser's content. In this case when form is being resized then webbrowser's first displayed line changes, which makes inconvenience.
I'm getting the first displayed htmlelement before the form is resized  and try to scroll that element into view after resize is completed.
But first displayed line is still being changed when resizing.

```
FirstDisplayedElement1:IHTMLElement;
// is declared in private section of TFormText

procedure TFormText.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var 
  NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  Resize:=True;
  FirstDisplayedElement1 := 
    GetFirstDisplayedElement(WebBrowser1);
end;

Function  TFormText.GetFirstDisplayedElement(WebBr:TWebBrowser):IHTMLELEMENT;
var
  ChildElems :IHTMLElementCOLLECTION;
  Element:IHTMLElement;
  iHTMLDoc: IHtmlDocument2;
  Element2:IHTMLElement2;
  ElemRect:IHTMLRect;
  i:integer;
begin
  Result:=Nil;
  if Supports(WebBr.Document, IHtmlDocument2, iHTMLDoc) 
then
  begin
    ChildElems:=(WebBr.Document as IHTMLDocument2).all;
    for i := 0 to ChildElems.length - 1 do
    begin
      Element := ChildElems.item(i, varEmpty) as IHTMLElement;
      Element2 := ChildElems.item(i, varEmpty) as 
IHTMLElement2;
      ElemRect:=Element2.getBoundingClientRect;
      if ElemRect.Top > 0 then
      begin
        Result:=Element;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormText.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FirstDisplayedElement1<> NIL then 
  FirstDisplayedElement1.scrollIntoView(True);
end;
```

How we can keep the first displayed line unchanged ?

Comment: I made a fast test (although not with Rio, but with XE7) and I can not reproduce what I understood your problem is. I loaded a large page (this page), scrolled down some amount, and started to resize the form. The top visible line stay fixed to the top of the browser, no matter which side of the form I use to resize. Tested with several scrolled locations of this page. Please provide directions how to reproduce.

Comment: I'll ask you to send your project to test on delphi rio. my mail: avrob@mail.ru

Comment: I don't think so, let's first try to agree upon what the proper test page would be. As I said, I tested with this very page. How does this page show up in your case, and did you possibly change any settings in the browser?

Comment: I also tested this page. after some errors the page was downloaded, and you were right - The first line stays fixed.

Comment: I'll ask you to test it with very simple html - consisting only p tags. I can send you such file - the first line is changing on form resizing.

Comment: the test was done in entirely new project. no changes were made in properties.

Comment: this is another site link. on this page first displayed line is being changed on resizing.  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/157196/Solved-View-able-html-elements-in-a-web-browser-c

Comment: Ok, I see now what you mean. Instead of getting an element, I was thinking about getting the ratio of current scrollpos and document height. Then during resizing, maintaining the same ratio by setting the scrollpos as the height changes. I tried this to get initial values: `scrollpos := ((WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body as HTMLBody).scrolltop;` and `docHeight := ((WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body as HTMLBody).scrollHeight;` but `scrollpos` is constantly 0, while `docheight` returns sensible values. Maybe you can try this path.

Comment: As it turned out the ratio of scrollheight and scrolltop is not constant on width resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Procedure FormCanResize is being called for three times when resize event occurs. ResizeStep variable is used to call GetFirstDisplayedElement(WebBrowser1) only once on FormCanResize first execution.
So this works.

```
ResizeStep:Integer;
FirstDisplayedElement1:IHTMLElement;
// are declared in private section of TFormText
// and are set to 0 and Nil in FormCreate

procedure TFormText.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth,
  NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  Resize:=True;
  if ResizeStep = 0 then
  begin
    inc(ResizeStep);
    FirstDisplayedElement1:=GetFirstDisplayedElement(WebBrowser1);
  end;
  if ResizeStep > 1 then ResizeStep := 0;
end;

procedure TFormText.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(ResizeStep);
  if FirstDisplayedElement1<> NIL then FirstDisplayedElement1.scrollIntoView(True);
end;

Function TFormText.GetFirstDisplayedElement(WebBr:TWebBrowser):IHTMLELEMENT;
var
  ChildElems :IHTMLElementCOLLECTION;
  Element:IHTMLElement;
  i:integer;
begin
  Result:=Nil;
  if Supports(WebBr.Document, IHtmlDocument2, iHTMLDoc) then
  begin
    ChildElems:=(iHTMLDoc.body.children AS IHTMLElementCOLLECTION);
    for i := 0 to ChildElems.length - 1 do
    begin
      Element := ChildElems.item(i, varEmpty) as IHTMLElement;
      if ((Element.offsetTop +Element.offsetHeight) > ((IHTMLDoc.body AS HTMLBODY).scrolltop)) then
      begin
        Result:=Element;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```